# CSS Transitions with inline-block

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a way to use CSS transitions or animations to smooth the effect on inline-block elements being re-positioned when we resize the window?

Like this, but with animation: http://jsfiddle.net/ricardogomes/hkw5h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean an effect like this? Maybe this helps:  http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-css-transitions.html

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have to look into it better, but for now thanks for the answer.

Comment: You should mirror whatever you link to, so that when the website changes or goes down, the content is still available for those seeking it.